# Updates php on Centos 7 but phpinfo.php show older version

Tags: centos, php

So, I'm removed all php on Centos 7 like this:

```
yum remove php*
```

then I'm install shut down the older php repository like this

```
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php54
```

and enable the new one

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
```

Then I install all I need:

```
  yum install php php-mbstring php-gd php-mcrypt php-pear php-pspell php-pdo php-xml php-mysqlnd php-process php-pecl-zip php-xml php-intl php-zip php-zlib
```

Then I check the php version via command line

```
[root@nube-preprod-clon ~]# php -v
PHP 7.2.29 (cli) (built: Mar 17 2020 11:36:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

And it's ok!But when I try to use this php version on the new version of owncloud I just installed it said:

[image]

So I crear a phpinfo.php file to check what the owncloud said:

[image]

What I am missing??

*** adding apache info from phpinfo.php
[image]

*** list of installed packages:

```
[root@nube-preprod-clon ~]# rpm -qa | grep http
httpd24-runtime-1.1-18.el7.x86_64
httpd24-httpd-tools-2.4.27-8.el7.1.x86_64
httpd-2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1.x86_64
httpd24-libnghttp2-1.7.1-6.el7.x86_64
httpd-tools-2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1.x86_64
httpd24-httpd-2.4.27-8.el7.1.x86_64
[root@nube-preprod-clon ~]# rpm -qa | grep php
php-pdo-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-pear-1.10.10-4.el7.remi.noarch
php-mbstring-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-json-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-cli-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-xml-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-process-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-mcrypt-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-mysqlnd-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-pspell-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-zip-1.18.1-1.el7.remi.7.0.x86_64
php-gd-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-common-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-fedora-autoloader-1.0.1-2.el7.noarch
php-intl-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
php-7.0.33-19.el7.remi.x86_64
[root@nube-preprod-clon ~]#
```

Sorry about my english.

Comment: From your post, it appears you are running PHP through Apache.  Have you made sure the Apache PHP module is running the correct version?

Comment: Please show the output of `grep -Rn libphp /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d`.  Make sure you are only loading the PHP7 module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK thanks to [@GracefulRestart](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/281407/gracefulrestart) found the simple "solution":

This user showed me where to look and what to look at more precisely I noticed that I had loading an old version of php in apache.

```
[root@nube-preprod-clon ~]# grep -Rn libphp /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php55-php.conf:6:    LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp55-php5.so
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/15-php.conf:9:    LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/15-php.conf:16:    LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7-zts.so
```

So I tried (and it worked) just move the .conf to .old, after that I could already see the correct version of php in my phpinfo.

[image]